# Upload images taken with app to MY OneDrive account

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I have an app which takes images.

What I want to know is, is it possible for these images, once taken to uploaded to a OneDrive account. I know I can have them uploaded to each user's OneDrive account, but this isn't what I'm looking for. I need the images all uploaded to one OneDrive account.

I've had a look around and can't find an answer for this.

So, is this possible, and do you know of anywhere I can get information on how to implement it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Hi check [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn263258.aspx) for OneDrive access, and some samples are provided [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh826531.aspx)